# Expanding only certain variables inside a heredoc

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, cluster

This is an extension of the question I asked .
[Passing directory from command line to shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505934/passing-directory-from-command-line-to-shell-script)

I have a script which writes another script using a heredoc. I need to be able to write unexpanded variables in the heredoc, so I use single quotes (`'EOF'`). However, I need one variable to be expanded. Given the script below, how can I write the value of `$sourcedir` inside the heredoc?

```
#!/bin/bash 

sourcedir="$1"
cd $sourcedir

find "$PWD" -maxdepth 2 -name \*_R1*.fastq.gz > list1

fastq_list=$sourcedir/list1 echo `cat $fastq_list` num_files=$(wc -l < 
 $sourcedir/list1) echo $num_files



cat > run_array_job.sh<<'EOF'

#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -j y
#$ -cwd -S /bin/sh
#$ -l h_vmem=10G
#$ -pe smp 12

if [ -z "${SGE_TASK_ID}" ]; then   echo "Need to set SGE_TASK_ID"   exit 1 fi


 BASEDIR=$sourcedir

 echo "BASEDIR" echo $BASEDIR

 BASEFILES=$( ls *_R1.fastq.gz)
 BASEFILES_ARRAY=(${BASEFILES})
 BASEFILE=${BASEFILES_ARRAY[(${SGE_TASK_ID} - 1)]}
 echo $BASEFILE


 ...................
 ...................

 EOF

 qsub -t 1-${num_files}  run_array_job.sh
```

I am running this script using

```
bash script.sh /home/dir/data
```

I am able to pass /home/dir/data as $1 to sourcedir but it also needs to be passed to BASEDIR , in array script which is submitted to cluster using qsub.

Comment: As simple as `BASEDIR=$1`. You need to escape all `$`'s in your embedded script. If you don't get what I mean I can write an answer.

Comment: @WeijunZhou the actual script is much, much longer than this (I know this from chatting with the OP), so escaping all `$` just to keep the value of one variable will be complicated.

Comment: @ron it would help if you could show how you want `$sourcedir` in the array script.

Comment: @terdon I made the change. BASEDIR = $sourcedir  is what I want, inside my array script

Comment: In this case I usually do `cat > wrapperscript.sh << EOF`, then put `run_array_job.sh $1` in the heredoc for wrapperscript.sh.

Comment: You can leave the `EOF` quoted so that you don't need to escape the `$`s for `run_array_job.sh`, but leave out the quote when you write heredoc for `wrapperscript.sh`

Comment: @WeijunZhou I didnt get the above two comments.I tried `BASEDIR=$1` suggestion,it did not work

Comment: That's because you used `<<'EOF'`, if you use `<<EOF` it will work but you need to escape all `$`'s. This is also why terdon edited your question to clarify.

Comment: How can I escape all `$'s`

Comment: Prefix them with backslash.

Comment: Is there any reason this needs to be a single heredoc? It doesn't look like it from the example since it's going into a file anyway, but maybe there's something about the real version that requires it.

Comment: @WeijunZhou There are too many variables, as this script is very long.Not sure if that would be the best way to do this.Also you mean escaping it only for the  variables or all the $'s no matter what

Comment: I have shown an alternative way above.

Comment: sure.can you send link to it

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90962/chat-room-for-https-unix-stackexchange-com-questions-505949-expanding-only-cert

Comment: @WeijunZhou I am in the chat room

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can most straightforwardly do this for your usage just by breaking your heredoc in two parts:

```
cat > run_array_job.sh<<'EOF'

#!/bin/bash -l
...
EOF

printf 'BASEDIR="%s"\n" "$sourcedir" >> run_array_job.sh

cat >> run_array_job.sh<<'EOF'
echo "BASEDIR" echo $BASEDIR
...
EOF

qsub -t 1-${num_files}  run_array_job.sh
```

This just builds the first part of the file, appends the single line that you wanted the variable available for at the end of that first part using `>>`, and then joins the rest of the document on the end in the same way.

You end up with the same coherent file at the end, and only write a couple of lines extra. If you have multiple variables to pass through, you can put them all in at once as well.

Comment: Thanks @Michael ,@Weijun also provided the same answer in the chat room.

Answer (score 4):

That's somewhat hard to do, since unlike with quotes, you can't just stop and restart expansion in an here-doc. But we could post-process the here-doc with `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcedir=/some/path
sed -e "s,%%sourcedir%%,$sourcedir,g" << 'EOF'
some commands here with $variables not expanded 
except for the special %%sourcedir%%, which is
EOF
```

Running that produces the output:

```
some commands here with $variables not expanded 
except for the special /some/path, which is
```

The `sed` command simply changes all instances of `%%sourcedir%%` with whatever the value of `$sourcedir` (as long as it doesn't contain commas; you'd need to change the separator for the `s` command to something else then.)

I changed the placeholder to another format for clarity's sake, but you could also leave it as `$sourcedir` and then use `sed -e "s,\$sourcedir,$sourcedir,"`. (Though note that it would also match `$sourcedirectory` and other similar variables, but not `${sourcedir}` even though that would be equivalent in the shell.)

Alternatively, use [GNU `envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) on the document, if you have it (it's part of `gettext`):

```
#!/bin/bash
export sourcedir=/some/path
envsubst '$sourcedir' << 'EOF'
some commands here with $variables not expanded 
except for the special $sourcedir, which is
EOF
```

Comment: Is `envsubst` GNU only?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, yep, seems to be.